# What kind of Strelitziaceae are these plants?

Tags: identification, tropical

I found these in Campinas in Brazil.  I suspect they are Strelitziaceae.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a traveler's palm or *Ravenala madagascariensis*. As the Latin name already suggests, originally from Madagascar and not Brazil.

Here a [picture](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/travellers-palm-ravenala-madagascariensis-trees-16139232312.html) for your confirmation. As you can read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenala), it is indeed a member of the *Strelitziaceae* family!